# ASP.NET Get table html

Tags: asp.net, html-table

I have a table on my ASP.net page something like this:

```
<table runat="server" id="resultsTable"></table>
```

I dynamically add content to the table, and it works just fine. However, I want to get the HTML of the table once I've added the dynamic content, i.e. something like this (formatting isn't important, I've just added it)

```
<table runat="server" id="resultsTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Hello!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Goodbye!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need the result as a string. Obviously I could do some looping and build my own table with the data, but I'd prefer to not do that if at all possible.

Comment: Do you need the content of each cell, or the whole table?

Comment: The whole table, HTML and all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially I though to just use the [InnerHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml(v=VS.71).aspx) or [InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext(v=VS.71).aspx) methods, but these are [not supported on the HtmlTable class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.innerhtml(v=VS.71).aspx).

So what if we use the Render method?  Something like this (take from [Anatoly Lubarsky](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/859.aspx))?

```
public string RenderControl(Control ctrl) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This method could obviously be cleaned up to handle closing the writers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I'd javascript the table markup to some hidden field (which is a server control) before the form gets posted.

```
<div id="tablediv">
<table>...</table>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var html = document.getElementById('tablediv').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('hfTableHtml').value = html;
```

EDIT: And yes, I'd worry about the request validation that is going to happen! You'd have to disable it or substitute those markup elements w/ something else before storing it into the hidden field

Answer (score 0):

Since your table is a server control, you may use its RenderControl method to obtain the render result:

```
    public static string GetRenderResult(Control control) {
        using(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) {
            using(HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                control.RenderControl(writer);
            sw.WriteLine();
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of way I can think of how to do this. The easy would be to surround the table in a  . Then on your vb/C# side simply call hold.innerhtml and it will return a string.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work "because the contents are not literal."

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in the `OnLoad` method of my page to convert your table to a string of HTML:

```
    string html;
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var xmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer))
    {
        this.resultsTable.RenderControl(xmlwriter);
        html = writer.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)  (several SO posts reference it.)